# Can Visual Studio Package built in VS2005 be deployed on VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I want to deploy a Visual Studio package built using VS2005 deploy on VS2010. I am able to register the package(using regpkg.exe) and I am able to see it as a project template in VS2010. However, the package has a editor page which is displayed as soon as we select this project template which does not get displayed and instead it shows a default editor of VS2010.

I am not sure if this is a problem registering the package or a problem between Visual Studio versions. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

We've seen this issue in attempting to launch the editor for existing projects that were originally created in VS2005.  We have an editor that handles a specific extension (.svc).  In VS2005, the .csproj had:

```
   <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="MyServices.svc">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Removing the `<SubType>Designer</SubType>` allowed the expected behavior (double-clicking on the file opened the plug-in) rather than the default editor.  Creating a new .svc file in VS2010 resulted in:

```
   <ItemGroup>
     <Content Include="MyServices.svc" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

That always seems to work correctly.